# Html5 Canvas stroke transparent gradient line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How do I create a transparent gradient stroke that using html5 canvas? I need it to go from one point to another and look like the below image.

[image]

At the moment I have got this:

```
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(1, 0, 100, 0);

gradient.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#d29baf');

ctx.lineWidth = 30;
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(fromXPos, fromYPos);
ctx.lineTo(toXPos, toYPos);
ctx.stroke();
```

This makes it look like a solid block though like:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Comment: @Blindman67 Nope. I'm going to award you the bounty when I can in 20 hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fill a shape

Use a shape and fill it with the gradient.

You can use CSS colour type `rgba(red,green,blue,alpha)` where red,green,blue are values from 0-255 and alpha is 0 transparent to 1 opaque.

To create a shape you start with ctx.beginPath() to create a new shape then use lineTo(x,y) to mark out each corner. If you want to add another shape using the same fill or stroke you use ctx.moveTo(x,y) to move to the first point.

**Note** many people use `ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(x,y);` but that works just the same as `ctx.beginPath(); ctx.lineTo(x,y);` As the first point after beginPath is always converted to a `moveTo` for any type of path object.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// draw first box (left of canvas)
ctx.fillStyle = "#ab7383";
ctx.fillRect(20,100,50,50);

// draw second box (to right of first)
ctx.fillStyle = "#904860";
ctx.fillRect(100,20,50,130);
   
// gradient from top of second box to bottom of both boxes
const g = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 20, 0, 150);
g.addColorStop(0, `rgba(${0xd2},${0xba},${0xaf},1`); // opaque
g.addColorStop(1, `rgba(${0xd2},${0xba},${0xaf},0`); // transparent
ctx.fillStyle = g;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(70, 100); // top right of first box
ctx.lineTo(100, 20); // top left of second box
ctx.lineTo(100, 150); // bottom left of second box
ctx.lineTo(70, 150);  // bottom right of first box
ctx.fill();   // fill the shape
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
```